# AngularJS: ngMobile has still a delay of 300ms

Tags: angularjs, cordova, touch

I use Phonegap 3.0 and AngularJS 1.1.5.

I want to remove the 300ms delay on touch devices. Therefore I integrated angular-mobile (see [v1.1.5 angular-mobile.js](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-mobile.js)).
In my app.js I have

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ajoslin.mobile-navigate', 'ngMobile'])
.config(function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
})
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/homeView.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

In my partial:

```
<a ng-click="showTime()" >Alert</a>
```

My Controller:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $navigate) {
  $scope.showTime = function () {
       console.log(Date.now());
   };
}
```

The text is printed, but you see that it is delayed by the 300ms because it does not appear right now in the log.

Can anyone help me with that?

Maybe I'm doing something really wrong ;-)

THanks!

Comment: Have you tried [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)?

Comment: No, is there a module you can load into angular as well? I used ngMobile, because it overwrites the default directive `ng-click` with a custom implementation which should work on browser and touch devices the same way....

Answer (score 1):

I switched to AngularJS 1.2 and am using the ngTouch directive from the angular code their! That works!